# Is there a way to get discord user information (avatar, account creation date, etc.) from users that are NOT in the same guild as my bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to add a command to my bot which shows a user's avatar and account creation date by entering their user id. While trying to do so i noticed that when using discord.js the user must be in at least one guild the bot is in too.

Is there any way to get user information just by a user's id?

Comment: The user wouldn't be cached if you are just trying to get them from all of Discord

Comment: No, the answer is no, immagine caching million of users just because you want to show their propic

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Simply use [client.users.fetch()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch) with the `force` option set to true.

`client.users.fetch("id", { force: true });` returns a promise as stated on the docs, you can either use async-await or .then() to get the user and its information.

A lot of people seem to skip past the `force` option, which is documented in the [BaseFetchOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/BaseFetchOptions) section.

Comment: Wouldn't work, the client doesn't have access to the user

Comment: Output (yes I'm using Glitch for the moment): https://i.imgur.com/Ijnytgr.png | Code: https://i.imgur.com/LtdB4EQ.png this user has no mutuals with my bot, and it works.